# How to INSERT correctly in a VARRAY of TYPE OBJECT?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, user-defined-types, varray

In this moment I'm working in SQL Developer and proving creation of different TYPES. For now this is the idea:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE actividad_t AS OBJECT(
    nombre varchar2(50),
    contenido varchar2(50),
    plantilla varchar2(50),
    nota float); 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE vActividad_t AS VARRAY(5) OF actividad_t;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE asig_pers_act_t AS OBJECT(
    dni varchar2(50),
    id_asig int,
    actividades vActividad_t,
    MEMBER FUNCTION calc_media RETURN FLOAT,
    MEMBER PROCEDURE mostrar_datos (SELF IN OUT NOCOPY asig_pers_act_t));

CREATE TABLE Asig_Pers_Act OF asig_pers_act_t;

INSERT INTO Asig_Pers_Act(dni, id_asig, actividades) VALUES
('11223344A', 3, vActividad_t(
  ('Actividad1', 'Contenido1', 'Plantilla1', 7),
  ('Actividad2', 'Contenido2', 'Plantilla2', 8.5),
  ('Actividad3', 'Contenido3', 'Plantilla3', 5),
  ('Actividad4', 'Contenido4', 'Plantilla4', 6.5),
  ('Actividad5', 'Contenido5', 'Plantilla5', 9)));
```

After execute the INSERT command the compiler show this in console:

```
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00907: falta el paréntesis derecho
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Someone can help and tell me how to INSERT correctly in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the elements of your varray as `actividad_t` objects.

The following works for me:

```
INSERT INTO Asig_Pers_Act(dni, id_asig, actividades) VALUES
('11223344A', 3, vActividad_t(
  actividad_t('Actividad1', 'Contenido1', 'Plantilla1', 7),
  actividad_t('Actividad2', 'Contenido2', 'Plantilla2', 8.5),
  actividad_t('Actividad3', 'Contenido3', 'Plantilla3', 5),
  actividad_t('Actividad4', 'Contenido4', 'Plantilla4', 6.5),
  actividad_t('Actividad5', 'Contenido5', 'Plantilla5', 9)));
```

Comment: @OP: In other words, each object must be created individually by a call to the object constructor; you can't create multiple objects simultaneously, with a single call to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A little thing cause a big headache, like always